Need help regarding record trigger flow
I am trying to update the status of lead record based on the status of campaign member record using a record trigger flow, it should work for multiple records.
can you tell me if it is required to bulkily the flow?


can you tell me if it is required to bulkily the flow?

Not from the perspective of handling multiple initiating records. This is handled automatically for you by things like Get Records and Update Records. You should still avoid things like queries in loops etc. though, and if you have a custom invocable method this must be written to handle bulk data (input and output arrays).
This is covered in the documentation.
